# Qt 5.5 - touchscreen-events only working in initial (first) window

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I've set up a basic Qt-Widgets-Application (Qt 5.5 community) with a simple QWidget "MainWindow" and an additinal QWidget "SettingsScreen".

Within the "MainWindow", touchscreen-events (handled by OS) are working as expected, but after opening the "SettingsScreen" all touch-events are executed on the desktop until I close the "SettingsScreen" using mouse or keyboard.

**Environment:**

- Ubuntu Studio 14.04.03
- Qt 5.5 Open Source Edition

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <settingsscreen.h>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:

    void on_btnExit_clicked();

    void on_btnSettings_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    SettingsScreen *wSettingsScreen;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "settingsscreen.h"
#include "ui_settingsscreen.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_btnExit_clicked()
{
    this->close();
}

void MainWindow::on_btnSettings_clicked()
{
    wSettingsScreen = new SettingsScreen(parentWidget());
    wSettingsScreen->show();
}
```

**settingsscreen.h**

```
#ifndef SETTINGSSCREEN_H
#define SETTINGSSCREEN_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class SettingsScreen;
}

class SettingsScreen : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit SettingsScreen(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~SettingsScreen();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_btnBack_clicked();

private:
    Ui::SettingsScreen *ui;
};

#endif // SETTINGSSCREEN_H
```

**settingsscreen.cpp**

```
#include "settingsscreen.h"
#include "ui_settingsscreen.h"

SettingsScreen::SettingsScreen(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SettingsScreen)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

SettingsScreen::~SettingsScreen()
{
    delete ui;
}

void SettingsScreen::on_btnBack_clicked()
{
    this->close();
}
```

I've just started developing with Qt, so please forgive me if I'm missing something essential :)

Any help would by highly appreciated!!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: MainWindow is derived from QMainWindow and settingscreen in derived from? Would be nice, if you can share the headers, too.

Comment: as a first guess: you probably need to connect the signals/slots

Comment: @Gombat MainWindow and SettingsScreen are derrived from QWidget afaik. I've added the headers to the original question for completeness.

Comment: @BogdanWilli the functions are working properly if using a mouse to click the buttons, so I assume the connections are OK (touch is handled on OS level) or are there additional signals for "touchscreen-events"?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the thing is QMainwindow or any base Widget of your application is able to properly synthesize the Unhandled touch screen events to Mouse events. So whenever you are creating a dialog/widget, make sure to set Mainwindow as there parent and in the constructor of the child widget use setParent(parent). Even I was facing this kind of Issue and this worked for me.