# Qt 5.5: application stops receiving mouseclicks from the touchscreen of Raspberry Pi

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi

My Qt 5.5 based application on the Raspberry Pi stops receiving mouse clicks from the touchscreen after for example closing a `QDialogBox`. It should be noted that the USB mouse keeps working properly.

The following small application also exhibits this problem. The main window contains only a single `QComboBox`. After starting the application, click the `QComboBox` on the touch screen and instead of selecting A, B or C, click on the desktop to let the selection disappear again. After this the widget does not receive anymore mouse clicks from the touch screen. If we select the `QComboBox` again with the USB mouse, by actually clicking it twice, we can again use the touchscreen.

It should be noted that in my main application after the 'repair' with the USB mouse a click on the touchscreen will only select for example the `QComboBox` even tough I click somewhere else. If I watch the mouse button events, normally every `MouseButtonPress` and `MouseButtonRelease` comes in pairs, that is two presses followed by two releases. Just before locking the touch screen I see an odd number of `MouseButtonPress` events in a row. The USB 'repair' next exhibits an odd number of `MouseButtonRelease` events in a row.

Note also that using the USB mouse to open the `QComboBox` and then closing it again by clicking on the desktop, will require **two** clicks from the USB mouse to repair itself as well. But the USB mouse will repair itself.

How can we avoid the touchscreen from becoming disabled?

File: `Bug.pro`

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Bug
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp MainWindow.cpp
HEADERS  += MainWindow.h
```

File: `main.cpp`

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "MainWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

File: `MainWindow.h`

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget * parent = 0);
};

#endif /* MAINWINDOW_H */
```

File: `MainWindow.cpp`

```
#include <QComboBox>
#include "MainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget * parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QComboBox * bx = new QComboBox(this);
    bx->addItem("A");
    bx->addItem("B");
    bx->addItem("C");
    setCentralWidget(bx);
}
```

According to `evtest` the touchscreen uses `FT5406 memory based driver`. I'm using a 7 inch touchscreen from Element14. Of course it is possible that I did not install the proper drivers, so if you need more information about installed packages, then please let me know and I will add it to the question.

P.S: This is probably the same problem as described in [Qt 5.5 - touchscreen-events only working in initial (first) window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624666/qt-5-5-touchscreen-events-only-working-in-initial-first-window?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I've been banging my head against this issue with the QComboBox for a few weeks using Qt version 5.3.2.  I've finally found that passing '-nograb' to your Qt application on the command-line works around this problem, but still haven't come across the true cause.  Hope it works for you!

Comment: The Qt bug report where I found the "fix": https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-33143